# Fetch data "with Elasticsearch dsl" Vs "with Django Rest Framework"

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm working on a `Django Rest Framework` project. I successfully implemented `Elasticsearch dsl` within my project. I indexed and synced all my `models` with `Elasticsearch`.
Now I can fetch my data both with `Elasticsearch` (and make searches on it) and with `Django Rest Framework`.

I want to know what is better to fetch data : `DRF` or `Elasticsearch`.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Depends... Elasticsearch is the quickest way to fetch data as it's NoSQL but to perform complex query you might want to use DRF/Python.

It relies on your requirement.